# Combobox Text property not changing in user control

Tags: wpf

I have a `list box` that has a list of user controls. Each user control has 5 combo boxes. I want to be able to read the selected text of each combo box in each user control from the main application. However, when I change the selection in the combo box, the text property of the combo box in the user control doesn't change when I read it in the main application.

Code-behind:

```
radQueryParamList.Items.Add(new TCardQueryParameters());
```

Xaml (This is just a data template for how to display a TCardQueryParameters object):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TCardViewQueryParamDataTemplate"> 
        <tcardqueryparam:TCardQueryParameters x:Name="TCardViewerParamUC" /> 
</DataTemplate>
<telerik:RadListBox Grid.Column="1"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TCardViewQueryParamDataTemplate}" Name="radQueryParamList" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
```

Where I loop over the list of user controls

```
string test = radTESTGACC.Text;//TEST combo box, Text property changes
//radQueryParamList is a listbox of user controls where TCardQueryParameters is the UC

foreach(TCardQueryParameters param in radQueryParamList.Items)
{
    //Each UC has a radGACC combo box in it, and I am reading what the user
    //selected for each user control here in the main app, but the text property 
    //never changes
    String gacc = param.radGACC.Text; //Text property DOESN'T CHANGE
}
```

I thought that each instance of the user control would keep its own state and I would just be able to read what the user selected for that combo box, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Have you bound the `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, or `SelectedIndex` property of your internal ComboBox to anything so it maintains its selection? I don't see it anywhere in your XAML

Comment: I have not, but I thought that since I was reading the actual combo box of the user control I wouldn't have to. That is why I was trying to do it this way, so I could just loop over the actual controls in memory and read the "Text" property. So it seems since I am passing a new view model in, I need to bind the selection to a property in this view model so that my main app can read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not bound the `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, or `SelectedIndex` property of your internal `ComboBox` to anything so it maintains its selection.

An `ItemTemplate` is like a cookie cutter. It contains the definition of the object, but not the object itself. Properties specific to the object's state are lost unless they are bound to something on the `DataContext` behind the template.

This is important to note for two aspects.

First off, to improve performance WPF usually unloads items which are not visible, which often results in items being re-created from their template anytime they are reloaded. An example would be when you minimize an application to the taskbar, then maximize it again. This is usually better on performance and memory usage, however it does mean you have to be sure you store the state of items that were created with a `Template` somewhere.

And second, by default `ListBoxes` use something called virtualization. A simple way of explaining this would be this:

Suppose you have a ListBox of 100,000 items. In your `ListBox`, only 10 items can be visible at a time. WPF will render roughly 14 items (the 10 visible ones, and then a few extra for a scroll buffer so you don't see anything unusual while scrolling). When you scroll to new items, WPF just re-uses the existing items that are already rendered, and just replaces the `DataContext` behind those items.

As you can guess, it is far better on performance to render 14 UI items instead of 100k items.

So to answer your question, you will probably want to bind either `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, or `SelectedIndex` of your `TCardQueryParameters` UserControl to a property on the `DataContext` (which in your case appears to be another different `UserControl`).

It should probably be noted that what you are essentially doing is creating a list of `UserControls`, assigning them to the `ListBox`, and then telling the `ListBox` that it should draw each `UserControl` with another separate `UserControl`. So although you are changing the `SelectedItem` in the template `UserControl`, that change is not being reflected to your `ListBox.Items` copy of the `UserControl`.

I'm guessing you probably don't want that, so would recommend removing your `ItemTemplate` completely.

Or better yet, create a new class object containing all the data for your `UserControl`, and adding that to your `ListBox.Items`. Then tell the ListBox to draw that item using a `TCardQueryParameters` UserControl as the `ItemTemplate`, like you have now.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That was a lot of very useful information. I am doing the last thing you said and adding a model to my listbox and having it render the user control off of that. Thanks!