# WPF user control does not update codebehind values

Tags: c#, wpf

I realize the question sounds a bit weird, so I'll explain as best I can.

I have a user control, basically a line that points can be added to and it draws a bezier curve based on the data, plus two textboxes for entering minimum and maximum values of the curve. When debugging the user control itself, everything seemed in working order, so I imported the project to the application I'm working on. It displays perfectly, the visibility toggle works (a checkbox bound to a boolean), the context menu functions work seemlessly. The only problem is, that in codebehind, nothing seems to have changed.

If I create the user control, then create five points in the GUI and hide it via the checkbox, if I access the boolean or the point collection from the codebehind (i.e. UserControl.PointCollection), the collection comes back with only the two default points, at the position they were when the control is initialized. I understand I need a binding to get codebehind changes to appear on the GUI, is there a similar requirement for GUI changes to reflect in the code? I come from a forms background and this makes no sense whatsoever to me.

Edit: Adding some sample code to help clarify

A simplified sample object:

```
namespace NodeViewHelper
{
    public partial class TimelineNodeControl : UserControl
    {
        public int Maximum;

        public TimelineNodeControl()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Maximum=100;
        }
        public void increaseMax(){
            this.Maximum++;
        }
     }
}
```

This object is then instantiated in XAML several times by another object as part of a template

```
<myClass:TimelineNodeControl/>
```

No matter how many times increaseMax is called, when I try accessing parent.TimelineNodeControl.Maximum, I get 100.

Comment: First, this question belongs on Stack Overflow, this site is for more cinceptual questions. Second, it's very hard to help you without seeing any of your code. Could you post a simple example code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: This sounds very related to [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20848221/302677) I recently posted. The short answer is, a Template in XAML is like a cookie cutter: it contains data about the object, but not the object itself. In order for a templated item to maintain data specific to the object itself, you need to bind it something in the DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your help (although only one comment is visible for some reason). As Rachel said, the problem was in the DataTemplate not being accessible through code-behind directly. I decided to bind the TimelineNodeControl's unique ID to its parent's(the model's) UID, and then search the visual tree for the TNC with the same uid to access the TNC directly, along with all the contained variables. Had to go through hell to turn the model into a DependencyObject though, this is the last time I'm modifying someone elses controls...

Comment: I re-added my comment :) Not sure why it got deleted in the migration, but I figured its useful and you referred to it in your answer, so it should probably be re-added. Glad you found a solution though!